# Laravel Queue - Prevent job retry on certain condition

Tags: php, laravel, exception, redis, queue

I call an API to send SMS and save it's response using Redis::throttle to limit the rate of the call to 5 calls every 60s with :

```
Redis::throttle('throttle:sms')->allow(5)->every(60)->then(function(){
    //->API call
    //->Save response
},function($error){//could not obtain lock
    return $this->release(60);//Put back in queue in 60s
});
```

I didn't specify any `$tries` because if the lock cannot be obtain, it count as a try and if I process a long queue and the lock cannot be obtain many time the job will fail without any "real" errors.
But I dont want the job to be processed forever, if there is a real error (like if the response cannot be saved) it should fail without retry especially if the error appends after the API call as a retry will send another SMS (which I definitely don't want).

What I've tried :

```
Redis::throttle('throttle')->allow(5)->every(60)->then(function(){
    try{
        $response = MyAPICall();
        $test = 8/0;
        saveResponse($response);
    } catch(\LimiterTimeoutException $e){
        throw $e;
    } catch(Exception $e){
        Log::error($e);
        $this->fail($exception = null);
        //$this->delete();
    }
},function($error){//could not obtain lock
    Log::info($error);
    return $this->release(60);//Put back in queue in 60s
});
```

If there is an exception because the lock cannot be obtain, I throw it back to let the queue handle it but if it's another exception, I log the error and fail or delete the job.
But it's not working with either `delete()` or `fail()`, the job is always retried.

How can I remove the job if there is an exception other than the `LimiterTimeoutException` ?

Comment: Imagine your external service fails with a 500, then it is nice that you retry the job and try again. I dont think your logic is clean or logical at all, try catch is kind of redundant if a job throws and error it will fail automatically.

Comment: @mrhn You're right, but if the API return an error 500 with my request, It will probably return another 500 if I retry with the same request. If a job throw an error, it will not just fail and stop, it will retry the job. If the error appends with the API request it's not a big deal because it will just retry to send a new request but if the error append after a successful API request (see my division by zero above), it will send the request (and an SMS) forever. I'm fine with not putting the API Call in the try-catch but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think i understand but not certain, think i got an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a "\" before Exception in my catch. Here is the fix code :

```
Redis::throttle('throttle:sms')->allow(5)->every(60)->then(function(){
    $response = myAPICall();
    try{
        $test = 8/0;
        SaveResponse($response);
    }
    catch (LimiterTimeoutException $exception){
        throw $exception;//throw back exception to let redis handle it below
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        $this->fail($exception);
    }
},function($error){//could not obtain lock
    return $this->release(60);//Put back in queue in 60s
});
```

I added `$this->fail($exception)` to make the job to show up as "failed" in Horizon.